# Iterative file search in python

Tags: python, file-search

I have a list of strings and three different text files containing all those strings (and some information about them) in no particular order.
Each file has two columns, the first is that string and the second is a float variable that has some information about the string. My goal is, to combine these files into one based on the string.
For example: Here is my list

```
    str_list = ['1abc', '2hhh', '333']
    fpy = open('file1.txt')
    fpz = open('file2.txt')
    fpx = open('file3.txt')

    for i in range(len(str_list)):
        for line in fpy:
             if str_list[i] in line:
                 print line
        for line in fpz: 
             if str_list[i] in line:
                 print line
        for line in fpx:
            if str_list[i] in line:
                 print line
```

the problem is, the code stops and breaks out of loop after the first search. It stops right after it finds the first string in the files. Can anyone help?

I am trying to do it in for loops

```
    str_list = ['1abc', '2hhh', '333']
    fpy = open('file1.txt')
    fpz = open('file2.txt')
    fpx = open('file3.txt')

    for i in range(len(str_list)):
        for line in fpy:
             if str_list[i] in line:
                 print line
        for line in fpz: 
             if str_list[i] in line:
                 print line
        for line in fpx:
            if str_list[i] in line:
                 print line
```

The code breaks out of the loop after the first search

Comment: Did you paste the same code twice?

Comment: OK, you can't iterate a file more than once like that. Try changing it to `open('file1.txt').readlines()` so that you have the file contents in a list instead.